# Getting errorlevel from system command

Tags: c, command-prompt, system-calls, errorlevel

I have a C project and at some point I call the system command below:

```
ret_val = system("@ECHO OFF\nFC /A /L /N C:\\tmp\\test.out C:\\bin\\win\\output.txt");
```

FC command basically compares the two files and supposed to return an error level.

If I call this command on command prompt, I can view the error simply by echoing the `errorlevel` variable. I have no problem here.

My question is I would like to have this error level in an int variable in my code. I don't want it to be seen on my terminal but at the same time I want this variable in order to analyze my comparison result. This `ret_val` variable is always 0, it's not the functionality that I need.

How can I get `errorlevel` value in my code?

Comment: sorry, cannot reproduce. I get 0 (no diff), 1 (diffs) and 2 (file(s) not found) depending on the arguments. [mcve] please?

Comment: Yes yes, I get the same results as you have. My problem is how can I get these values (0, 1, 2) in my code? I don't want to see it by echoing the errorlevel variable.

Comment: What `ret_val` gives you?

Comment: `ret_val` contains that for me. that's why I said I couldn't reproduce your issue. that's why I'm asking for a [mcve]

Comment: I'm sorry but my real system call is this:
ret_val = system("@ECHO OFF\nFC /A /L /N C:\\tmp\\test.out C:\\bin\\win\\output.txt");
Does that change the result?

Comment: I failed to follow Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, sorry again!

Comment: that changes everything... only the `echo` command is executed: that's why you get 0 returncode. You don't need that `@echo off` command. if you want to stop output, just redirect output/err with `>NUL 2>NUL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `system` command only executes the first line of your string, so it executes `@echo off`, which doesn't change default return code, and you always get 0.

Of course, you could

- paste the text in a .bat file and execute this .bat file
- use commands chaining: `@echo off && FC /A /L /N C:\\tmp\\test.out C:\\bin\\win\\output.txt`

but in your case, since you have only one command to call, just call it without the `@echo off`

```
ret_val = system("FC /A /L /N C:\\tmp\\test.out C:\\bin\\win\\output.txt")
```

`system` doesn't need echo to be turned off. Only batch file execution defaults to verbose. System calls are silent (they don't print the issued commands).

Comment: That's not your proposed solution! Moreover, isn't it weird that you use os.system in C language?

Comment: oooops too much python :) sorry fixed the typo!

Comment: BTW this behavior (only executing first line) only happens on Windows. On linux-like systems, it will execute both commands.